# Cookies error when connect via ssh port forwarding

Tags: php, cookies, ssh, cross-domain, portforwarding

I have a PHP script running on the remote server inside private network. And I need to give only access to it via ssh port forwarding (ssh -L ....) remote port 80 to local 8080. The script sets cookies for auth purposes. And if I'm trying to log in browser discard cookies with error "set-cookie domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host url". But this works ok if I log in inside the private network.
The scripts set cookies using "HTTP_HOST"
`setcookie('auth',$hash,time()+$sesstime,"/",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],false,false);`

So I see cookies comes with correct address when connect via port forwarding as via internal network access.
Next log for port forwarding access (my address is 192.168.32.2)

`Set-Cookie: auth=431d622765774d602236744a6472324c417c712b194e377130771f64783b7b1a3379306656033a2473; expires=Thu, 01-Apr-2021 19:06:04 GMT; Max-Age=18000000; path=/; domain=192.168.32.2:8080`

And next for internal network access:

`Set-Cookie: auth=001228333034422a366337452e6667435573656816157d673430427f636763447e6d632c1c566f6e64; expires=Thu, 01-Apr-2021 19:04:51 GMT; Max-Age=18000000; path=/; domain=10.10.1.2`

More variables:

```php
["REMOTE_ADDR"]=> string(11) "10.10.1.2"
["HTTP_HOST"]=> string(14) "192.168.32.2:8080"
["SERVER_NAME"]=> string(11) "10.10.1.2"
```

Is there any solution? I need to setup correct port forwarding access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies are not port specific, so removing port from the cookie domain will solve this issue.

> 8.5.  Weak Confidentiality
>
> Cookies do not provide isolation by port.  If a cookie is readable
> by    a service running on one port, the cookie is also readable by a
> service running on another port of the same server.  If a cookie is
> writable by a service on one port, the cookie is also writable by a
> service running on another port of the same server.  For this reason,
> servers SHOULD NOT both run mutually distrusting services on
> different ports of the same host and use cookies to store security-
> sensitive information.

from [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-8.5).
And the domain does not contain port number. ([RFC 1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034#section-3.5))